# Excel freeze in loops after few seconds until it finish, even immediate window

Tags: excel, vba, loops, optimization, freeze

I have a bunch of codes like:

```
Sub dataManage()
    fastMacrosENABLE
  
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer
  
    For myRow = 1 To 50000
        SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
        Debug.Print myRow; " -- "; SecondsElapsed
    
        For myColumn = 30 To 500
            'do some stuff...
        Next myColumn
    Next myRow

    fastMacrosDISABLE
End Sub
```

where `fastMacrosENABLE` optimize the running by:

```
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = Not opt
    .DisplayStatusBar = Not opt
    .EnableAnimations = Not opt
    .EnableEvents = Not opt
    .ScreenUpdating = Not opt
End With
With Worksheet
    .EnableCalculation = Not opt
    .EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = Not opt
    .EnablePivotTable = Not opt
End With
```

macros runs fast (considering all the loops) but what surprise me is that after around 5 to 10 seconds, excel freezes until macro is finish, and thatwise even the immediate window. When the macro ends all comes to normal, and even the immediate window shows the last like 200 lines of logging

as you can imagine, that Debug.Print is just only to estimate the running time, and go for a coffe, a walk, or to sleep to next day, je je

**is that possible to avoid that freezing and have the immediate window reporting Debug all process along?**

Comment: Excel freezing means (in most cases) the macro has not finished yet and is still running. This is a normal behaviour. Actually the code where it says `do some stuff...` is executed 23,5 million times (due to your nested loops). I expect that to take more than one day to run through (depending on what "some stuff" exactly is). If each operation of "some stuff" only takes 0.1 seconds this means over 652 hours runtime. And even 0.01 seconds means over 65 hours runtime.

Comment: yes, it takes some time, some of those "do some stuff" are pretty simple (check if a cell has a value or no, or do some calculations), other more complex. That I counting with.

Comment: Well, as I told you this will take years, if you do that for 23,5 million cells. That is too much. The only way to get arround this is do it for **much** less cells (change your loops).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct Q

> is it possible to avoid that freezing

Add some `DoEvents` to your code. One inside the outer loop but outside the inner loop might be sufficient.

```vb
Sub dataManage()
    fastMacrosENABLE
  
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    StartTime = Timer
  
    For myRow = 1 To 50000
        SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
        Debug.Print myRow; " -- "; SecondsElapsed
        DoEvents

        For myColumn = 30 To 500
            'do some stuff...
        Next myColumn
    Next myRow
    fastMacrosDISABLE
End Sub
```

Note that this will slow down your code a bit.

That said,  your "do some stuff" code better be pretty well optimized...

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about DoEvents, let's try  (as said, is not that really the problem with speed, is mostly the unknown end time, with this I probably solve it ;-)